# Error when try to find array elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How could I find the "checkboxes" elements to make an array with them? I don't want to make the variable public because there are a lot of elements.

This error appears: Assets/_TES/Scripts/CheckboxEnabledSaver.cs(13,40): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.GameObject[]' to`CheckBoxes[]'

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using SickscoreGames.HUDNavigationSystem;

public class CheckboxEnabledSaver : MonoBehaviour 
{
private CheckBoxes[] checkboxes;
public string file = "myFile.txt";

void Start()
{
    CheckBoxes[] checkboxes = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("TESOROS").GetComponents<CheckBoxes>();
}

public void SaveCheckboxes()
{

    bool[] checkboxEnabled = new bool[checkboxes.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < checkboxes.Length; i++)
        checkboxEnabled [i] = !(checkboxes [i].sCollider.enabled);
    ES2.Save(checkboxEnabled, file);
}

public void LoadCheckboxes () 
{
    if(ES2.Exists(file))
    {
        bool[] checkboxEnabled = ES2.LoadArray<bool>(file);
        for(int i = 0; i < checkboxes.Length; i++)
        {
            if(checkboxEnabled [i])
            {
                checkboxes [i].sCollider.enabled = false;
                checkboxes [i].ChangeIcon ();

            }

        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Which one of these is line 20?

Comment: Change `GetComponent` to `GetComponents` as `GetComponents` returns array while the other one returns a single object. Notice the 's' in it. Voted to close as a simple typo issue.

Comment: @Jerodev It's line 13. Sorry!

Comment: @Programmer I've updated the code adding 's' to GetComponent, but now this error appears: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
CheckboxEnabledSaver.SaveCheckboxes () (at Assets/_TES/Scripts/CheckboxEnabledSaver.cs:19)
CheckBoxes+<ExecuteAfterTime>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () (at Assets/_TES/Scripts/CheckBoxes.cs:174)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)

Comment: That's a whole different error. Create a new question for that and don't use that error as the title since it will be closed. It is better to double-click on the error and post the line of code that's causing it in your new question

Comment: @Programmer ok, but it's so strange because all works fine when I write "public CheckBoxes[] checkboxes;" and delete the line "CheckBoxes[] checkboxes = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("TESOROS").GetComponents<CheckBoxes>();". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Two possibilities: You don't have a GameObject named `TESOROS` or you do but that GameObject is not active. Check your spellings. If not sure, copy the name directly. Also make sure that it is not deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

As an answer to your second problem (Null Reference" exception) -

In your Start method you are declaring a local CheckBoxes array which is hiding the class field declaration - use

```
void Start()
{ 
  checkboxes = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("TESOROS").GetComponents<CheckBoxes>();
}
```

Comment: The error in the question is *"Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.GameObject[]' toCheckBoxes[]"* Your answer did not address that. Although it discussed another issue not

Comment: The answer is referring to the error OP reported after the initial fix by Programmer. At present OP hasn't posted another question for that as suggested - so I posted this answer pre-emptively. I have clarified the answer.

Comment: Ok. I thought OP said he's getting that error at `CheckBoxes[] checkboxes = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag`. If that's the case then `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag` is returning null as programmer said too

Comment: I guess the method may still return null - so that needs checking for in the code - but the local variable declaration will be the problem if it does not return null.

Comment: Yes it will be a problem when used in the `SaveCheckboxes` and `LoadCheckboxes`  functions.